# Pagination approach in NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code:

```
app.post('/pepe/query/', function(req, res) {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM mutations";
  if (req.body.start.length !== 0) { //From an HTML form
    query = query + " WHERE pos>=" + req.body.start;
  }
  app.get('/pepe/query/:number', function(req2, res2) {
    var pages = 10 * req.param2("number") - 10;
    query2 = query + " LIMIT " + pages + ", 10";
    if (req.body.output == 1) {
      pool.query(query2, function select(error, results, fields) {
        res.render('index.html',{data:results, error:null});
      });
    } else if (req.body.output == 2) {
      query2 = "SELECT count(*) FROM (" + query + ") AS table1";
      pool.query(query2, function select(error, results, fields) {
        res.send(results);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

However, this approach does not work, cause I send information from a form via `POST` to `/pepe/query`, but it does not work.

My aim would be to go to `/pepe/query/3` for example, and go to page 3 (results 21-30).

Comment: Could you explain how exactly your app "waits for a number"? Why do you have `/pepe/query` at all if results will only be returned when `/pepe/query/:number` is called, and why do you have one inside the other?

Comment: Cause I can't do this better. For this reason I call for help.

Comment: There is no need to nest the app.get inside the app.post, as @ev0lution suggests, you are better off using a single GET request and utilising express param method: `app.param('number', function(req, res, next, number){
 console.log(number);
});` Then GET /pepe/query/:number then return the results.

Comment: Single `GET`? And where do I post?

Comment: Why do you need to POST?

Comment: You should assume your server is stateless as other suggested above. Just have a single `GET` endpoint what handles both the case the user passes a number (`pepe/query/3`) or the case the user doesn't pass anything (`pepe/query/`).

Comment: See my answer, hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
app.get('/pepe/query/', function(req, res) {
    var start = req.query.start;
    var number = req.query.number;
    //Logic here.
    res.send(results);
});

<form method="GET" action="/pepe/query/">
   <input name="start" type="text" id="search" />
   <input name="number" type="text" id="number"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It throws the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` referring to line 3 in my code: `req.params.start.length`.

Comment: Try checking what req.params object contains when you call the endpoint.  It should have two values `{start  : 1, number : 2 }` for example.  It might be because there is no length property on a number object, so you may need to do `if(req.params.start)` but not using `length`.

Comment: Try `req.query` instead of `req.params` sorry.